# Resuse of Async task code in my various file

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, background-process

I want to create an class file for Async task operation and from creating the object of that class file i want to access these method of async task with no of different class files with different parameters.

**Methods of Async task include:-**

**OnPreExecute()**-Want to start progress dialog same for each class.

**doInbackground()**-Want to perform background operation(like getting data from server) means passing parameter different for each class.

**onPostExecute()**-Dismiss the progress dialog and update the UI differnt for each class.

Now I'm writing the async task in my every class as inner class like the following:-

```
class loaddata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddNewLineitem.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                }
            });
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest(url_foralldropdowns,
                        "GET", params1);

                compoment = json.getJSONArray(COMPONENT_CODE);

                for (int i = 1; i < compoment.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = compoment.getJSONObject(i);

                    String code = c.getString(CODE);
                    list_compoment.add(code);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            loadSpinnerData();
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

And JSON parser class is as follows:-

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;


    }
}
```

And in oncreate() I call this and it works fine:-

```
new loaddata().execute();
```

Comment: sorry to say bt it not works at all..send with the above so it helps me a lot..appreciate for your work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reuse Aysntask with different parameters. For this

1.Create an Interface so that we can reuse,pass and receive parameters

```
public interface BackgroundListener {

public Object[] startBackgroundWork(Object... objs);
public void endBackgroundWork(Object... objs);
public void beforeBackgroundWork();


}
```

2.Create a Class Extending Asyntask

BackgroundHandler.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class BackgroundHandler extends AsyncTask<Object, Object[], Object[]>{
BackgroundListener backgroundListener;


public void setBackgroundListener(BackgroundListener aBackgroundListener)
{
   this.backgroundListener = aBackgroundListener;
}
@Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
  backgroundListener.beforeBackgroundWork();
}
@Override
protected Object[] doInBackground(Object... objs) {



    return backgroundListener.startBackgroundWork(objs);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result[]) {
    backgroundListener.endBackgroundWork(result);
}
```

}

Using in Activity

A.java

```
Class A extends Activity implements BackgroundListener
{

   ...onCreate()
   {

          BackgroundHandler backgroundHandler =  new BackgroundHandler()         
          backgroundHandler.setBackgroundListner(this);
          backgroundHandler.execute(new Object[]{url1});//pass any number of parameters of any object type 
          // show loading bar
   } 
   public void beforeBackgroundWork()
  {
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(A.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        .....
  }
   public Object[] startBackgroundWork(Object... objs)
   {
       // access and type convert the passed parameters like objs[0], objs[1]
      //.... some time consuming stuff
      //.... some time consuming stuff
           String url_foralldropdowns = objs[0].toString();
            List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest(url_foralldropdowns,
                    "GET", params1);

            JSONArray compoment = json.getJSONArray(COMPONENT_CODE);
            //Create new list_compoment here instead of global declaration
            for (int i = 1; i < compoment.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = compoment.getJSONObject(i);

                String code = c.getString(CODE);
                list_compoment.add(code);

            }



     retrun new Object[]{list_compoment};
   }
   public void endBackgroundWork(Object ...obj)
   {
        pDialog.dismiss();// hide loading bar
       //access resultant parameters like  objs[0], objs[1]
      //user list_component will be in obj[0]

   }
}
```

Similarly we can reuse in B.java

```
Class B extends Activity implements BackgroundListener
{

  ...
 ....
    public void beforeBackgroundWork()
  {
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(B.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        .....
  }
   public Object[] startBackgroundWork(Object... objs)
   {

   // access and type convert the passed parameters like objs[0], objs[1]
      //.... some time consuming stuff
      //.... some time consuming stuff
           String url2 = objs[0].toString();
            List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest(url2,
                    "GET", params1);

            JSONArray compoment = json.getJSONArray(COMPONENT_CODE);
             //Create new list_compoment here instead of global declaration
            for (int i = 1; i < compoment.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = compoment.getJSONObject(i);

                String code = c.getString(CODE);
                list_compoment.add(code);

            }



     retrun new Object[]{list_compoment};

   }
   public void endBackgroundWork(Object ...obj)
   {
      pDialog.dismiss();
       .....
          //user list_component will be in obj[0]
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry friend not getting..:(

Comment: You are trying to reuse your code to download and parse json - so only  the url varies for different request right?

Comment: Yes the Url and the parameters passing to the Url is different for various class..I appreciate that you try hard for me..Thnaks.

Comment: please check the code i have added http connection code which is also reused

Comment: I have an JSon parser class but Getting error in backgroundhandler.execute()..can i post my whole code that i m executing.

Comment: ok post, pls try this code n let me know, atleast it can solve the situation

Comment: see my above code i can done this but i have to write the loaddata for each class to execute with new url and parameter i want this it to one class and access in any activity with diff url n parameter...please send some code on including of the above so it helps me alot..your code is getting error fr me..please some helps..

Comment: whats is the error on backgroundhandler.execute()? please specify

Comment: please post the error also - may the interface BackgroundListener was not implemented

Comment: No dude its working only i want to start the progressdialog on the start of task like as in onPreexecute().please suggest me what can i add.or change in ur above code.

Comment: Dude..progressdialog not displayed..i make the changes that you mentioned in your code..bt nt working:(

Comment: did you called pDialog.show()? in beforeBackgroundWork ? any error or warnings in logcat?

Comment: Sorry..this is my mistake its getting other error but it works now...Thanks for your help..hates off to you for your patient and hardwork that you made for me..working like a charm now..really appreciate for your work..Thnk you so much..:)

Answer (score 0):

`Asyntask` is just a class like others. Apart from the main inhertited methods of AsyncTask you can create your own methods, constructor etc. So just create a separate class in separate file. pass the context as parameter of the constructor. you can pass other values also to define the tasks.

```
class Loaddata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public Loaddata( pass the params){
        ... set the params
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {

        // pDialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: StinePike:-I tried this but its not works for me can you please provide me solution for that.so it helps me a lot.

Comment: please post your existing code showing what you have tried. then i guess we can find the problem

Comment: i was suggesting to create class file for only asynctask .. not an activity.. you can see my edited answer if it helps you